# Android firebase value event listener nested inside another listener fetching data in an abnormal way

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

this is my first question in Stackoverflow.
I use firebase in my android app, and my DB schema is as follows:

Users schema:

[image: Users schema]

and

Posts schema:

[image: Posts schema]

Now, I have used a recyclerview to show the posts by users. I have implemented SingleValueEventListener where I get list of Posts by users and another eventlistener nested inside to fetch the User's name and profile picture.

The code is as follows:

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("Posts");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    final PostsPOJO postsPOJO = data.getValue(PostsPOJO.class);
                    images = postsPOJO.getcontent_post();

                    //Nested listener to fetch User's name and profile picture from another node "Users/UserID"
                    final Query userDetails = databaseReference.child("Users/"+postsPOJO.getUserID());
                    mListener = new ValueEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {

                            String username = dataSnapshot1.child("Username").getValue(String.class);
                            String profilePicturePath = dataSnapshot1.child("ProfilePicture").getValue(String.class);

                            list.add(new PostsPOJO(postsPOJO.getUserID(),profilePicturePath ,username, postsPOJO.getTimestamp(),postsPOJO.getPostText(),postsPOJO.getLocation(),postsPOJO.getcontent_post()));
                            Log.d("datalist", postsPOJO.getUserID()+","+profilePicturePath +","+username+","+postsPOJO.getTimestamp()+","+postsPOJO.getPostText()+","+postsPOJO.getLocation()+","+postsPOJO.getcontent_post());

                            newsFeedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    };

                    userDetails.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(mListener);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Now, the problem is that the first UserID which the nested listener gets, it fetches all the Posts from that particular UserID first and then goes on to the next UserID for example if it gets UserID : 1, then it will give all the posts from that User first and then go on to the next one, if its UserID : 2, vice versa. I want the Posts data by the UserID associated with that post.

I have implemented `.orderByKey()` but no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put post Ids under user data like

Users -> 1 -> Posts -> [postId-1,postId-2,postId-3]